# all checkboxes need to be checked and unchecked with the main checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me with this?

I have two `div`s. In one `div`, I have a checkbox named `allcheck`, and in the other other `div`, I have checkboxes with name `outcheck`. If I check `multiple`, all need to be checked, and if I uncheck `multiple`, all should be unchecked. input radio is class of `allcheck`.

```
$('.inputradio').click(function(){

    $("INPUT[name='outCheck']").each(function () {
        if (allCheck.checkbox== true) {//multi check is checked
            this.checked = true;
        } else {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

This is the `div` for main checkbox

```
<div id="actions"><div id="box">
<ul><li class="inputradio"><input name="allCheck" type="checkbox" ></li>
<li class="multiple"><a href="#" class="bt btleft">Multiple</a></li>
```

This is for child checkboxes:

```
<ul><li id="outcheckbox"><input name="outCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
```

Even if one child is checked, if we check the main checkbox, all need to be selected. The code I posted is just inverting the check.

Comment: Post the html markup also. That would help!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095039/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931622/uncheck-all-other-checkboxes?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959703/jquery-to-uncheck-all-checkboxes-within-div?rq=1

Comment: please post correct html in question itself. It's difficult to read from comments.

Comment: oops sorry..i've posted it now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('input[name=allCheck]').click(function(){
   $("INPUT[name='outCheck']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

This will toggle all checkboxes having name `outCheck` on click of `allCheck`.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4YV8/1/)

---

**UPDATE**

see updated [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4YV8/3/)

This works as expected. If all checkboxes are manually checked then main checkbox also changes and vice versa if one child is unchecked, main checkbox also gets unchecked.

Comment: Thanx a lot...its working for all but..if all outcheck are selected or deslcted the main check box is not changng :-/

Comment: the updated demo works..but when integrated in my code it works on the third click..first the multiple alone is getting checked then dechecked and on the third click all the outcheck are checked

Answer (score 1):

This code implements functionality to select and deselect all checkboxes

select and deselect

```
$(".select-all-checkbox").click(function () {
       $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
```

If one item deselect then button CheckAll is UnCheck

```
$(".mainCheckboxClass")
        .click(
                function() {
                    if ($('input[class=mainCheckboxClass]:checked').length === $('input[class=mainCheckboxClass]').length)
                        $('.select-all-checkbox').prop("checked", true);
                    else
                        $('.select-all-checkbox').prop("checked", false);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var $ch = $("input[name='outCheck']").change(function() {
    $all.prop('checked', $ch.filter(':checked').length == $ch.length);
}),
$all = $('input[name=allCheck]').click(function () {
    $ch.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wKgZV/1/

This will select and deselect main checkbox automatically depending on how many `outcheck` checkboxes are checked.

Comment: if i add it in code..the main checkbox is not automatically checked if i check all the childs.. :(