# How to check uncheck checkbox all at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

All I want is to check / uncheck all of the choices with one check button.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

<p> Select pet: </p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="dog" value="dog"> Dog </p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="cat"> Cat </p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="bird" value="Tbird"> Bird </p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="checkall" value="checkall"> All </p>
```

what code / codes am I missing? I need "All" to uncheck / check all choices if it is chosen by the user. I use xampp for this one.

Comment: you can use pure JS for this or jQuery.

Comment: Start with some introductory JavaScript.  What you're looking to do is create an element to click for "select all", attach a click event handler to that element, and in that handler set the checked state of all of your check boxes.  Each of these pieces of functionality can be found easily on Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [all checkboxes need to be checked and unchecked with the main checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371678/all-checkboxes-need-to-be-checked-and-unchecked-with-the-main-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (jQuery):

```
$("#checkall").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Just add the `id` attribute to the checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="checkall" value="checkall">`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for you checkboxes and use Javascript:

```
<form .....>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" name="dog" value="dog" />
    <!--rest of the checkboxes with the same class name but different names and values follow-->
    <button type="button" class="checkedAll">Check All</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var checked = false;
        $('button.checkedAll').click(function() {
            checked = !checked;
            $('.myCheckboxes').prop('checked', checked);
            if (checked) $(this).text('Uncheck All');
            else $(this).text('Check All);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an id attribute with the value "petForm" to your form element.

```
<form id="petForm" action="process.php" method="post">
```

You can use the following pure Javascript.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var form = document.getElementById("petForm");

    if (form) {
      var checkAll = form.querySelector("input[type='checkbox'][name='checkall']");
      var checkBoxes = form.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:not([name='checkall'])");

      checkAll.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        for (checkBox of checkBoxes) {
          checkBox.checked = this.checked;
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

It adds an event listener to the document that waits for the DOM to be loaded, then identifies the form by the added id attribute.  If it finds the form, then it stores the "checkall" input element and all the other input elements of type checkbox in the form in two different variables.  After that it adds an on change event listener to the "checkall" checkbox input element that sets all other checkbox input elements in the form to the same value as the checkall checkbox input element.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/653gLxya/) of the code above running.

If your form contains additional checkboxes that you don't want checked by the checkall checkbox, you'll need to modify the way checkBoxes is populated.  Similarly if you have multiple collections of checkboxes then you'll need to find a way to differentiate between them.