# Checkboxes - Individual refused tests boxes (English, Math, Sci) and "Entire Exam" checkbox, checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, google-sheets

I need 4 checkboxes on one row for a Google Sheet. They represent (3) school exams refused. The last box is when all of them are refused.

2 months ago, I knew nothing about VBA and since then I have made a series of  macros with 6 year old like coding. They are not pretty but they work. Now I am beginning at square one with Apps Script or whatever coding you suggest/recommend I use. I'm sure the coding between the two (VBA and Apps Script) look similar to you but they look totally different to me.

I do not have any code or experience for this. I searched around and found something (on this site) that is really close to what I am looking for.

Here is the example that I found:

[all checkboxes need to be checked and unchecked with the main checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371678/all-checkboxes-need-to-be-checked-and-unchecked-with-the-main-checkbox)

This is for a Google Sheet. I have 3 exams that my students have to take - English, Math and Science but have a tendency to refuse to take them. They may refuse all of them, some or none. I need 4 checkboxes - one for each individual exam they refuse and one if they refuse all of them. If you check all of the individual boxes (done over a period of time), the "Entire Exam" box is checked and the individual boxes become unchecked. If you directly check the "Entire Exam" box first, any checks that may be on the individual boxes become unchecked.

The checkboxes will be on the same row but individual cells. English will be F2, Math will be G2, Science will be H2 and Entire Exam will be I2.

The reason I can't have all the individual exams boxes and the Entire Exam box checked at one time is because I need to distinguish between partial exams and entire exams not taken. I will need to count the number of individual exams that were refused as "Partial exams" as well as entire exams.

Another thing I want to do is reduce the number of clicks so a suggestion that may come up to just have 3 boxes for the individual exams and if they are all checked, that would mean the entire exam had been refused, that's 2 extra clicks of the mouse. This sheet will most likely be used during a sudden flood of refusals just an hour before the exams begin so just checking the "Entire Exam" box if the case may be, would be simpler/faster than checking all 3 individual boxes.

How does this work? Do you assign the code to the checkbox itself?

I would appreciate any feedback and help. And if you have any sites that you can refer me to start my learning in this, please share. Thank you. Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your Eng, Math, Sci, and Entire columns; F, G, H, and I respectively; are set to actual Sheets checkboxes (select F2:I, menus→Insert→Checkbox).
[image: Simple screenshot showing what the above might look like in Sheets.]

If you've never run Google Apps Script on a spreadsheet, perhaps step through a decent tutorial, e.g. the first few sections of [this Ben Collins guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/beginner-guide-to-google-apps-script/).

Once you have code running, try a script that watches for edits to the Sheets file and responds with your required checks and changes.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // these four 'settings' give the script the checkbox range. UPDATE IF RESTRUCTURING!
  var checkboxRange = {
    left : 6,
    right : 9,
    top : 2,
    bottom : 1000
  };

  // where was the edit performed?
  var editSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editCol = e.range.getColumn();

  if(editRow < checkboxRange.top  || editRow > checkboxRange.bottom) {return};
  if(editCol < checkboxRange.left || editCol > checkboxRange.right ) {return};
  Logger.log("User edit was in the checkbox area.");

  if(editCol == checkboxRange.right) {
    Logger.log("User changed an 'Entire Exam' checkbox; seeing if now checked.");
    if(editSheet.getRange(editRow,checkboxRange.right).getValue()) {
      Logger.log("Yes, user checked that 'Entire Exam' checkbox. Clearing Partials.");
      editSheet.getRange(editRow,checkboxRange.left,1,3).uncheck();
    }
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("User changed a 'Partial' checkbox; seeing what's there now:");
    var partials = editSheet.getRange(editRow, checkboxRange.left, 1, 3).getValues();
    Logger.log(partials);
    if(partials[0][0] && partials[0][1] && partials[0][2]) {
      Logger.log("All Partials are checked; clearing Partials and checking Entire.");
      editSheet.getRange(editRow,checkboxRange.right).check();
      editSheet.getRange(editRow,checkboxRange.left,1,3).uncheck();
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("User changed a Partial, but not all true; paranoid unchecking Entire.");
      editSheet.getRange(editRow,checkboxRange.right).uncheck();
    }
  }  

}
```

I believe it matches your described desired behaviour. In English, it:

- Tests for and ignores edits outside the F2:I1000 range.
- Otherwise, tests if the change was: "checked an Entire Exam box"; and if yes, clear Eng, Math, Sci.
- Otherwise, see what the subject checkboxes are, and

  - If they're all checked now, uncheck them and check Entire instead
  - Otherwise they changed a Partial, but they're not all true, so uncheck Entire Exam, for cleanliness.

I put a few `Logger.log()` messages in there instead of comments. After making an edit in the Sheet, you can see what the Logger generated based on your edit by returning to the Script Editor and from the menus, choosing View → Logs. Once you're happy with how your Sheet and script are working, you can remove the Logger calls.

Finally, a caution; once you get it working for yourself, have other people who will use the Sheets file make a few test edits to see it working and confirm your script is running before the big day—no nasty surprises!

Comment: Thank you so much. I will go through the Ben Collins guide as you recommend. That is a great idea about having others test the Sheet. I may use it one way while others may use other ways and come up with problems.

Comment: I'm curious to hear if it works on your actual Sheet. Let us know, and [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers.

Comment: I put it in my Sheet today and it works just how I wanted it to. I added those 6 lines from the Ben Collins guide that creates the "My Custom Menu". I needed to adjust the bottom and top values. Perfect!!! Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Have you made sense of the code? Having to edit someone else's script can be a headache. Let us know when it breaks or your needs change. Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand what the 2 pikes do (||)

Comment: In English, we don't want to continue if the edit row is left of the left column or right of the right column of checkboxes. The `||` operator is the "or" in that sentence. Later there are `&&` "and" operators to only check Entire Exam box if Partial1 [is true] "AND" Partial2 "AND Partial3. Check out this [JavaScript operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) explanation for all the other things you can do in `if` tests. (Google Apps Script is based on javascript.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining that and for the link for the JavaScript operators